# Access Specifier Does Not Change Accessibility Level. What does this mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax-error

I am just wondering what this message means on visual studio. Does this mean that by default variables inside classes are set to private. I cannot get a clear answer to this question anywhere.

This is my code:

```
#pragma once
class number
{
private: // <-- that is grey in the IDE and it shows the text box when you hover over it
    int random_number; 
public:
    number(int x); 
    int get_number() const { return random_number; }
    void set_number(int number) { random_number = number; }
    ~number();
};
```

Comment: [Cppreference - classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes) is a good starting point for class related questions. Beyond that, I recommend reading a C++ book.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify anything, `private` is implicit when you define a class by means of the `class` keyword. In other terms, the following definitions are identical:

```
class C {
    int i;
};

class C {
private:
    int i;
};
```

The opposite is true if you use the keyword `struct` instead of `class`:

```
struct C {
    int i;
};

struct C {
public:
    int i;
};
```

That is, Visual Studio is telling you that the `private` is superfluous. Your data member is a private one in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You probably accidentally wrote public or private two times consecutively. And the second access specifier does nothing.
Variables inside classes are set to private by default and variables inside structs are set to public, so this can be the cause of the message too.